# Won't there be problems if I use UI element tagging to identify elements?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Assume I have a group of labels and buttons. They are irrelevant to each other.
I tag labels dynamically from 1, so I can uniquely identify them when they are tapped.

```
label.tag = 1
label2.tag = 2
...
```

Then I also have my buttons:

```
  button.tag = 1
  button2.tag = 2
  ...
```

(note that these elements could be images, etc)

Now, when I use a tap recogniser and receive the sender, and identify the sender via it's tag and access the Label/Button to change it's text contents, will the function `ViewWithTag` know I tapped the label not the button or button not the label?

How should I use tags to confirm there won't be collisions? (Bare in mind, I might be using database Ids as tag values ,etc).

Ideally, tags could be an array, where the first element could represent a group, or something.

Cheers

Comment: Update your question wth some concrete code clearly showing a possible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You* are the assigner of tags. It is *your* responsibility to ensure that your tags are assigned in such a way that any call to a particular UIView's `viewWithTag:` **cannot** encounter, among the subviews of that view (or the view itself), an ambiguity (that is, two views with the same tag — what you call "collisions").

It is for this reason, among others, that Apple keeps making moves — which so far have been abortive — towards deprecating `viewWithTag:`.

As you rightly say, an array would be better. That is exactly what `@IBOutletCollection` is for. If you had one set of views in one outlet collection and another set of views in another outlet collection, then you can easily and without ambiguity find a view in one outlet collection and instantly specify the corresponding view in the other outlet collection — because their indexes are same.

Comment: What I usually do in this situation is what Sweeper recommends, i.e. give the corresponding pairs _different_ tags related by some elementary conversion, such as adding/subtracting a constant. However, I really should move towards outlet collections, and I am aware of this.

Comment: Interesting... I do not use storyboards to create my UIs. So not sure how relevant IBOutletCollection is?

Comment: @harrylakins Then you could simply have a pair of arrays that you form in code, maintaining references to your labels / buttons respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> will the function ViewWithTag know I tapped the label not the button or button not the label?

No.

To solve this problem, you can do something like this:

Give each label a tag of (1000 + id), give each button a tag of (2000 + id), give each image view a tag of (3000 + id). This way, the tags conflict only when there are a thousand labels or buttons or image views (very unlikely). I also recommend you to extract these "base numbers" as constants to achieve late-binding.

```
let labelTagBase = 1000
let buttonTagBase = 2000
// etc.
```

And you use them like this:

```
someLabel.tag = labelTagBase + someID
```